# How do controllers pass the instance variables defined within a method to the corresponding views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

Instance variable defined within a method of a class are available to the other methods of that class. But how instance variable defined within a method of controller class are available to the corresponding view of that method or better to say how the instance variables are passed to the views?

Answer (score 1):

This [post](http://www.thesatya.com/blog/2009/06/rails_instance_variables.html) puts it in the simplest possible way:  A rails view is part of the controller and not a separate class, so it can access instance variables of the that particular controller.